# Interact with elements behind a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 divs (div1, div2). The div1 is front, div2 is behind. I want to use div1 to make a mask for changing color mode (change color temperator for all the site). So the div1 need to stand at highest place (z-index=999999). However, in this situation, I cannot interact with other element behind div1. How can I do?

```css
#div1{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
  z-index:99999;
}
#div2{}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2">
<input type='button' value="click me">
</div>
```

Comment: i think you are looking for this? https://jsfiddle.net/ga0gpc5p/

Comment: Perfectly! You save my life :)) Thank so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events:none`

https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

```css
#div1{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
  z-index:99999;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#div2{}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2">
<input type='button' value="click me">
</div>
```

Comment: Additionally, here's another SO post with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909314/make-an-entire-webpage-be-tinted